# Alguém pode me dizer se conhece algum pacote do R para usar com a família distribuição quase-beta neste modelo?

Tags: r

Alguém pode me dizer se conhece algum pacote do R para usar com a família distribuição **quase-beta!**

modelo:

```
pse <- (ps~tr+tra+ds+(1|prop)+(1|in)+(1|nr),data=pes1,family = "???????")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível dar uma resposta adequada sem saber como são seus dados. Mas a princípio você pode usar *glm* com a família "quasi" e especificando a função de variância para ser a mesma da Beta:

```
pse <- glm(ps ~ tr + tra + ds + (1|prop) + (1|in) + (1|nr), data = pes1,
           family = quasi(link = "logit", variance = "mu(1-mu)"))
```